# Armadillo: Obtain raw data from matrix/vector as array

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am searching for something like this:

```
fmat A     = randu<fmat>(4,5);
float **a  = A.to_array();     // Return matrix as float**
```

Does anybody know how one could do this in `Armadillo`?

Comment: A double pointer (eg. `float**`) is one of the worst things that C++ has inherited from C.  It's best not to use such functionality in any new code. It's unsafe and takes a lot of boiler plate code to keep track of properly. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches by not using it. If you need to pass data around, it's better to pass references to `fmat` objects instead.  For example, `void fn(const fmat& A)`

Comment: Hi @mtall, the reason why I'm using this is because I want to pass the raw matrix to a CUDA function which expects a `float**`.

Comment: If you want GPU based matrix multiplication, use Armadillo with [nvBLAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvblas) instead of standard BLAS. In general, using the GPU for matrix multiplication is only useful for matrix sizes greater than 5000x5000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no function to return an array of pointers. You *can* access the underlying buffer with the [`memptr()` method](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr):

```
float *a = A.memptr();
```

You can also get a pointer to any matrix column with the [`colptr()` method](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#colptr). I'm not sure why you might need an array of pointers but you could build one like this (uncompiled and untested code):

```
std::vector<float *> av;
av.reserve(A.n_cols);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < A.n_cols; ++i)
   av.push_back() = A.colptr(i);

float **a = &av[0]; // a remains valid while av is in scope
```

Note that Armadillo stores data in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major#Column-major_order).

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean by "*can*" that this might be unsafe at some point? :)

Comment: The docs state that using `memptr()` is not recommended unless you know what you're doing. But I was only emphasizing that although there wasn't a function to do exactly what you wanted, there was another way to get access to raw memory.